# Rails routing problem, action being skipped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-routing

I'm having a bizarre issue where it seems as if Rails is skipping the run of my particular Action. I have two environments that I am running this in. One (development) works fine and runs the action. The other (staging) is not running the action.

The error is that Rails can't find a template in the views directories for my given action, which is only supposed to respond with JSON (no template). I've done logging in the action and it just simply isn't being run. Rails immediately fails saying that the view doesn't exist.

Just to cover my bases, I've verified that the code is indeed the same, that my routes file is exactly the same, and that my rails version (3.0.1) is exactly the same between the two env's. Any help would be excellent here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this comes in the department of facepalm. One of our developers had committed a new controller with a different file name but the same controller class name as another. It must be that in development rails was loading the new controller first, and so the old controller would override it and the issue was hidden. In stage however, it seems that the new controller was loaded last, which cannibalized our controller class and method, screwing everything up.

I'd be interested to know if others have encountered this problem in rails. May need to patch the controller loading code to always use the same sort mechanism (seems like file name would be most natural).